# SharePoint Apps with built in lists

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin, office-365

So I am working on a pretty simple app that helps users find/navigate documents in my companies Quality Management System, however this app also needs to keep track of how many times any document is clicked/pulled up.  To keep track of the number clicks, I wanted a list that lives in the app web that can will be updated whenever a document is selected.

However, my problem is that I want this list to be deployed/created when the app gets installed.  I know I could have some javascript check to see if the list exists in the app web, if not create it and everything is good to go.  But, I want to know if it is possible when developing the app to say "hey this list(s) is required as a back ends for my app" and have the lists created when the app is deployed?

Currently, I have been doing all my development in office 365 with Napa tools but I feel like if this is possible I would have to use visual studio?  If so how would go about doing this?   All my research(google) keeps giving me articles on how create lists using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I took my own advice and moved away from Napa tools and brought my project into visual studio.  Once I was in visual studio I was able to add a SharePoint list to my project.  When I deployed this project and tested it in Office 365 the list was there.  I navigated to the list in the browser and added some items to it, closed the debug sessions and restarted it...when I returned a second time my list and the added items were there.

Links for anyone else that wants do this:

[Creating lists in an app via VS](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/create-list-in-sharepoint-2013-apps/)

[How to view app web lists in the browser](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharatgupta/2013/03/10/sharepoint-2013-app-model-how-to-view-list-list-settings-inside-app/)